# Usage of most recently

Tags: word-usage

In the sentence below-

> Since 2001, the JeM and Azhar have claimed responsibility for several terror attacks that resulted in the deaths of dozens of innocent persons, including, **most recently**, the February 14 attack on a CRPF convoy in Pulwama.

Is **most recently** used properly? I think it is wrong and one must use **The most recent one**. Help me clear this doubt.

Thanks in advance.............

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is correct English. The commas show how the adverb intrudes into the sentence to modify the the sense. It adds additional information so it is a parenthetical remark. This is fairly common.

> Joe is, happily, a kind man

This means that Joe is kind, and I am happy about it.

Comment: could you give me some other examples please?

Answer (score 1):

I think that is okay and a common way things like that are written in the news. It's a way of abbreviating and also being somewhat vague. If they said "the most recent one" they would be comparing it to a specific incident and they don't want to do that. They want to compare it to a lot of incidents and point out the most recent, if that makes sense.